# regex find <img src='url' /> in html

Tags: python, regex, urllib2

I haven't played with regex yet and was looking for some help to find just the  parts in the string.

Example Of img tags:

`<img border="0" alt="background, images, scarica, adobe, art, rainbow, colorful, wallpaper, tutorial, abstract, photoshop, web, pictures, wallpapers" width="192" height="120" class="h_120" src="http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/thumbs/1/74/736679.jpg" />`

I'm just trying to get the url of the src out of a large html file.

Comment: It has been said time and time again, but you should never use regular expressions to parse HTML, which is not a regular language. Which language are you using?

Comment: You really need to read [this SO question about using regexes on HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: [*Very loud sigh.*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/489560)

Comment: People get so needlessly upset about this. This might be OK, or not, depending on the scenario. If your goal is to scrape 1000 pages on someone's site that all look about the same and grab image URLs, a regular expression is a perfectly easy and quick way to do that. If your goal is to write a spider that parses pages all over the Internet, or to write a web browser, then I wouldn't recommend regex.

Comment: I'm using python's urllib2 library.

Comment: @OrenMelzer The img tags I'm attempting to scrap are pretty much the same throughout the pages I'm scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
page_images = [image["src"] for image in soup.findAll("img")]
```

---

Install `BeautifulSoup` using: `pip install beautifulsoup4`